How do i fix the issue of Invalid Bytecode, code: invalid argument when deploying?
I am building a dapp on Ethereum using hardhat and next.js() which utilises scaffold-eth-2. When I try to deploy my contracts I get the error processing, invalid bytecode bytecode: value, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0). I have tried changing the library I am using to fix the problem but it still gives me the same error. Here is my contract giving me the error:
pragma solidity 0.8.27;

import "./PoseidonSMT.sol";

contract registerMerkleTree is PoseidonSMT {

    /// The maximum depth of the Sparse Merkle Tree (SMT)
    uint256 public immutable smtTreeMaxDepth = 20;

    /// Mapping to track commitments and prevent duplicate registrations
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) public commitments;

    /// Mapping to track roots and validate their existence
    mapping(bytes32 => bool) public rootsHistory;

    //bool private initialised;

    constructor() {
        initializeTree();
        //initialised = true;
    }


    function initializeTree() private {
        __PoseidonSMT_init(smtTreeMaxDepth);
    }
    
    /// @notice Register a voter by providing a commitment
    /// @param commitment_ Commitment to add to the voter tree
    function register(bytes32 commitment_) public {
        // Check if the commitment has already been used
        //require(initialised, "Registration: tree not initialized");
        require(!commitments[commitment_], "Registration: commitment already exists");

        // Add the commitment to the tree
        //TODO fix this line causing invalid bytecode invalid argument
        //_add(commitment_);

        // Update the mapping to prevent duplicate registrations
        commitments[commitment_] = true;

        //save the root to history
        rootsHistory[getRoot()] = true;


    }
    

    /// @notice Check if a voter is registered
    /// @param _commitment Commitment to check
    function checkIfUserExists(
        bytes32 _commitment
    ) public view returns (bool isValid){
        bytes32 commitment = bytes32(_commitment);
        //Get the node
        SparseMerkleTree.Node memory node = getNodeByKey(commitment);
        
        return node.value == _commitment;
    }

    /// @notice Reset the tree to its default state
    function deleteTree() private {
        __PoseidonSMT_init(smtTreeMaxDepth);
    }
    
}

The poseidon SMT tree code can be found here : https://github.com/rarimo/voting-contracts/blob/da5fd06346b80dcbcb197e510b1c2f9c1be2ab13/contracts/utils/PoseidonSMT.sol
Here is also my deploy code:
 import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { DeployFunction } from "hardhat-deploy/types";
import { Contract } from "ethers";

/**
 * Deploys a contract named "YourContract" using the deployer account and
 * constructor arguments set to the deployer address
 *
 * @param hre HardhatRuntimeEnvironment object.
 */
const deployYourContract: DeployFunction = async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  /*
    On localhost, the deployer account is the one that comes with Hardhat, which is already funded.

    When deploying to live networks (e.g `yarn deploy --network sepolia`), the deployer account
    should have sufficient balance to pay for the gas fees for contract creation.

    You can generate a random account with `yarn generate` which will fill DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY
    with a random private key in the .env file (then used on hardhat.config.ts)
    You can run the `yarn account` command to check your balance in every network.
  */
  const { deployer } = await hre.getNamedAccounts();
  const { deploy } = hre.deployments;

  await deploy("YourContract", {
    from: deployer,
    // Contract constructor arguments
    args: [deployer],
    log: true,
    // autoMine: can be passed to the deploy function to make the deployment process faster on local networks by
    // automatically mining the contract deployment transaction. There is no effect on live networks.
    autoMine: true,
  });

  await deploy("registerMerkleTree",{
    from: deployer,
    log: true,
    autoMine: true,
  });
};

export default deployYourContract;

// Tags are useful if you have multiple deploy files and only want to run one of them.
// e.g. yarn deploy --tags YourContract
deployYourContract.tags = ["YourContract"];

I have been stuck with this error for two weeks and have not been able to find the cause of the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have a look at your constructor. It takes no arguments.
Now if you look at your deployment script, it specifies args: [deployer]. Remove this argument and this error should disappear.
You can't give arguments upon deployment if the constructor isn't written to accept those arguments.

Thanks for your help but you are looking at the wrong deploy code that one is for a different smart contract it is registerMerkleTree.

Did you add the wrong deploy code? Maybe replace it with the right one?
